# How to get booleanfield values that are True

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to get all the users that's profile's BooleanField are True.

**What i am trying to do:-**

I made a feature of Users that are banned and I made a BooleanField for each user, AND i am trying to get all the Users that's profile's BooleanValue is `True`.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    block_users = models.BooleanField(choices=BLOCK_CHOISES,default=False)
```

**The Problem**

```
def block_users(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    blocked = Profile.objects.filter(block_users=profile.block_users)

    context = {'blocked':blocked}
    return render(request, 'blocked.html', context)
```

When i runthis code, This only shows me user that's value is `False`. BUT i want users that's Value is `True`.

I have no idea how to get it.

Thanks in Advance.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to list out users as per logged in user. I mean, if logged in user is Blocked, it will list blocked users and if not it will list not-blocked users.

this instead:
In your models.py, create a related_name

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile_user",unique=True)
    block_users = models.BooleanField(choices=BLOCK_CHOISES,default=False)
```

In views.py, when you will do "request.user.profile_user.block_users", it will give logged in users blocking status.

Now, if you want users which are blocked, filter directly with True.

```
Profile.objects.filter(block_users=True)
```

Comment: Thank You very Much for your Effort. BUT You want me to put`request.user.profile_user.block_users` before it ?

Comment: Its upto you. If you want your logged in users status and want to use it further, you can add it. But if you want to list only Blocked user, filtering with True will do the trick. No need of request.user.profile_user.block_users. in this case

Comment: BUT i want to show the blocked users which is blocked by the user that is logged in.

Comment: Then it will be a total different scenario. Add another field in you model with name blocked_by(This will help you to find who has blocked whom).
This will be a foreign key to User model. Change logic of how you insert in your model.
When you want to fetch data you can do:
Profile.objects.filter(block_users=True,blocked_by=request.user.profile_user).